# Representing a list of strings as a numpy array of their ascii codes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What I have is a list of strings. What I would like to do with it is to convert it to a 2D numpy array, where `result[i, j]` would be the ascii code of j-th character from i-th string (preferably as float).

I know I can use `list(map(float, map(ord, single_line_from_list)))` to get a list of my floats, convert it to 1D array, and then loop all of that to get my final array. But I wonder if there's a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using a `list` of `str` instead of an ndarray with one of numpy's string types?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you think you gain by having `dtype=float` when all the values fit in `dtype=uint8`, which is much less storage and the values usually convert as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested list comprehension.

```
import numpy as np 

array = np.array([[float(ord(character)) for character in word] for word in words])
```

Comment: Pre-building an ndarray and then filling it will avoid the temporaries.

Comment: This doesn't actually return a 2D array, just an array of lists. Any idea on how to fix that (just pad columns that are shorter than the max lenght with zeros).

Answer (score 0):

One option could be create a sparse matrix using `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` and then convert it to dense:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

lst = ['hello', 'world!!']
​
idx, idy, val = zip(*((i, j, ord(c)) for i, s in enumerate(lst) for j, c in enumerate(s)))   ​
coo_matrix((val, (idx, idy)), shape=(max(idx)+1, max(idy)+1)).todense()

#matrix([[104, 101, 108, 108, 111,   0,   0],
#        [119, 111, 114, 108, 100,  33,  33]])
```

---

Or use `izip_longest(python2)/zip_longest(python3)` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

list(zip(*izip_longest(*map(lambda s: map(ord, s), lst))))
# [(104, 101, 108, 108, 111, None, None), (119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33, 33)]
```

This gives a *2d* list. You can use `fillvalue` parameter to fill the Nones:

```
list(zip(*izip_longest(*map(lambda s: map(ord, s), lst), fillvalue=0)))
# [(104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 0, 0), (119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33, 33)]
```